# Group list into groups by the the index range of the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a **source** integer list with numbers from 0 to 50.

Then I want to have a grouped **target** list that means:

```
group1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
group2: 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
group3: etc... ,30
group4: etc... ,40
group5: etc... ,50
```

The groupFactor here is 5.

How can I group my integer list basing on that group factor which could be any number?

**UPDATE**

If the group factor is 6
there would be an additional:

```
group6: etc... ,60
```

Comment: How about the result if group factor is 6

Comment: Updated question :-)

Comment: But you said that the numbers only go up to 50. This doesn't make sense. I would expect with a group factor of six that the groups would be 0-7, 8-15, 16-23, etc.

Comment: It's not really clear how you want to group them. By value? By number of elements? By formula (e.g. `val < n * 10`, where `val` is the value of an item and `n` is the factor)? Will the values always be consecutive?

Comment: Well the group factor is a computed value. Its value also depends on the size of the source list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague but for the sample you provided, I found this fancy group by :)

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int i=0; i <= 50; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}
var result = list.GroupBy( n => (n-1)/10 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Let k be your group factor.  Group your list by multiplying the list member by k then dividing by 50, and grouping the sequence on the resulting quotient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> input = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        input.Add(i);
    }

    List<List<int>> output = input.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, i = (int)(x / 10) }).GroupBy(y => y.i).Select(z => z.Select(a => a.x).ToList()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I get 6 groups where the 6th group has one item which is '50'. I expected to have the 5th group`s last item '50'. Sorry my fault my source list starts with 1 not 0...

Comment: Then subtract one : ((x - 1) / 10)